# Access to a web page via a robot

Tags: node.js, http, request

I need to occasionally access an HTML page to update a database. This page is easily accessible via a web browser, but when I try to access it via a node.js application it doesn't work (the website detect that the request is made by a robot). However,

- The robot request contains the same headers (including the
  `user-agent`) that the web browser request.
- The robot request doesn't contains `referer` header or `cookie` header, but the browser request either.
- The IP of the robot is the same that the IP that I use
  to browse the website.

In my eyes the robot request and the browser request are strictly identical. Nevertheless they are processed differently.

I'm running out of ideas... Maybe the request contains metadata like "this request was sent by node.js" but it would be really weird.

EDIT, here is a code sample :

```
// callback (error, responseContent)
function getPage (callback){

    let options = {

        protocol : 'https:',
        hostname : 'xxx.yyy.fr',
        port : 443,
        path : '/abc/def',
        agent : false,

        headers : {

            'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language' : 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
            'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache',
            'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
            'DNT' : '1',
            'Host' : 'ooshop.carrefour.fr',
            'Pragma' : 'no-cache',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' : '1',
            'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0'
        }
    };

    https.get (options, function (res){

        if (res.statusCode !== 200){

            res.resume ();
            callback ('Error : res code != 200, res code = ' + res.statusCode);
            return;
        }

        res.setEncoding ('utf-8');
        let content = '';

        res.on ('data', chunk => content += chunk);
        res.on ('end', () => callback (null, content));

    }).on ('error', e => callback (e));
}
```

EDIT : here is a comparison of the requests/responses :

**Mozilla Firefox**

request headers :

`GET /3274080001005/eau-de-source-cristaline HTTP/1.1
Host: ooshop.carrefour.fr
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache`

response headers :

`HTTP/2.0 200 OK
date: Wed, 11 Jul 2018 21:25:25 GMT
server: Unknown
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
age: 0
x-varnish-cache: MISS
accept-ranges: bytes
set-cookie: visid_incap_1213048=G8a0mWzmQYi0GKuT2Ht7YeQ9QVsAAAAAQkIPAAAAAADvVZnsZHK18dQQxHakBprg; expires=Thu, 11 Jul 2019 11:17:56 GMT; path=/; Domain=.carrefour.fr
incap_ses_466_1213048=/2NKHS4HXU0T7FpkwpJ3BsV1RlsAAAAAAY3wbUkXacAceu2NkgUrhw==; path=/; Domain=.carrefour.fr
x-iinfo: 7-11020186-11020187 NNNN CT(1 2 0) RT(1531344324722 0) q(0 0 0 0) r(4 4) U12
x-cdn: Incapsula
content-encoding: gzip
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2`

response content : expected HTML page

**Node.js robot**

request headers :

`Accept : text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language : fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Cache-Control : no-cache
Connection : keep-alive
DNT : 1
Host : ooshop.carrefour.fr
Pragma : no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests : 1
User-Agent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0`

response headers :

`content-type : text/html
connection : close, close
cache-control : no-cache
content-length : 210
x-iinfo : 1-17862634-0 0NNN RT(1531344295049 65) q(0 -1 -1 0) r(0 -1) B10(4,314,0) U19
set-cookie : incap_ses_466_1213048=j34jMBWkPFYT7FpkwpJ3Bqd1RlsAAAAAVBfoZBShAvoun/M8UFxPPA==; path=/; Domain=.carrefour.fr`

response content :

```
<html>
<head>
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">
<script src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=5074a744e2e3d891814e9a2dace20bd4,719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3">
</script>
<body>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you put up a code sample? I'm curious to see how the request is made (format)

Comment: Yes, you have exactly described the capabilities of a [web crawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler).  Please attempt to utilize an implementation such as puppeteer or even selenium web driver and come back if you run into concrete issues while trying to use it.  As it stands right now, this question is too broad.

Comment: @IlanP Of course, I edited my question to add the code sample.

Comment: Awesome, structure looks good; when you say it "knows" its a robot; can you put up the error received when you log it? you're imitating the call properly; it does not send a "this was sent via node JS" marker as you've mentioned; I'm curious now what type of error you are seeing; perhaps its CORS related; just trying to isolate the variables :)

Comment: @zero298 I don't know much about networking. So first I need to understand well the problem before solving it. As I said, in my eyes the two request are strictly identical, but it's not the case. So I would like to know how two request with same content, same headers end same IP can be different.

Comment: @IlanP I've just edited my question.

Comment: Your bot got picked up by incpsula's protection mechanism; so they secured their site using this service that inspects "spoofed" headers but ALSO you failed to notice in Firefox you got a cookie returned with two important properties; visid_incap_1213048=G8a0mWzmQYi0GKuT2Ht7YeQ9QVsAAAAAQkIPAAAAAADvVZnsZHK18dQQxHakBprg; expires=Thu, 11 Jul 2019 11:17:56 GMT; 
incap_ses_466_1213048=/2NKHS4HXU0T7FpkwpJ3BsV1RlsAAAAAAY3wbUkXacAceu2NkgUrhw==; path=/; these are dynamic sessions created by your client, which are passed along your session. Your bot is not passing them; + anti-forgery on headers blocks

Comment: Can you share the URL you're attmpting to scrape? you can probably get those incapsula sessions off the cookie and pass them through;

Comment: @IlanP The cookies are in the response not in the request. When Firefox send a request there is no cookies. It receive a response that charge it to set cookies but this response contains also the HTML page.

Comment: Reference: https://www.incapsula.com/website-security/access-control.html you need those cookies in the sessions

Comment: @IlanP Here is the [kind of URL](https://ooshop.carrefour.fr/3274080001005/eau-de-source-cristaline) that I attempting to request.

Comment: Ha, I immediately got blocked on Chrome for having a proxy add-on; Incapsula's very smart they check if your rendering JS (which requires a client) and instead of spamming CAPTCHAs they utilize dynamic cookies; it won't be easy to scape; you need to work on getting those cookie sessions and passing them through

Comment: @IlanP I noticed that when a captcha is displayed, a simple reload (without validate the captcha) is enough to access the page (probably because when you reload, cookies are sent). Their protection is strange, when I try to access the page without cookies via a web browser sometimes it works, sometimes a captcha is displayed. How can they check if you render JS before sending the page if the content is sent in the initial request ?

Comment: They provides clients a CDN type JS script which must be rendered client-side; it's one of the more advanced techniques to make sure the client is an actual browser capable of reading the JS. You're attempting to scrape a well protected site; your code is fine; your logic is good; but the site your hitting is well protected; they also use redirects and this cookie session as well;

Comment: @IlanP I don't understand what I'm supposed to do with cookies. They send me cookies with the response and I should send them back in other request ? But there is no other requests except for simulate a reload when a captcha is displayed. I already tried it, but it was a failure.

Comment: I just tried to script and grab the cookie, which I have: visid session part 1: visid_incap_1213048
visid session part 2: zMsa+ktoQTa8gNcKKc9fcCOCRlsAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABIioAS49BNLPzotSqj598f
sess session part 1: incap_ses_149_1213048
sess session part 2: qvE+KQ/vD0SWtDd2WWARAiOCRlsAAAAA+uDYbY55a7j6vECk89EEWQ== but I'm not sure how the cookie is sent back; I can't emulate your issue because I am unable to access this site from my end; it's protection is very nice; can you put up the request headers after you've browsed to a second page? hit page 1, navigate anywhere and check the request.

Comment: @IlanP [Here](https://pastebin.com/XQTLYk8w) it is. Have you tried a proxy hosted in France to access the site ?

Comment: This is what you need to emulate: Cookie: __cfduid=d42f0480d87fde5cba735c9af71f87e631531348491; s=0ssbhh2mkuvlfv4vij2e88ujt3; _ga=GA1.2.1550351251.1531348489; _gid=GA1.2.1236221568.1531348489; c[carrefour.fr][/][visid_incap_1213048]=fJE1JELyTq2WZpuRBGm8mA%2BGRlsAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABaFFHGIjd9N%2F1mGcWpIB6a; c[carrefour.fr][/][incap_ses_507_1213048]=LqkcPGC1BH%2Bq57e%2FRDoJBw%2BGRlsAAAAA3WUN233ruNxSE2rcdXfnBw%3D%3D; __atuvc=3%7C28; __atuvs=5b46860931da098c002; __atssc=google%3B3; _gat=1 <---- keep in mind CFDUID is the most difficult grab; the other two are easy

Comment: @IlanP I've done it, [here](https://pastebin.com/6us8JNRs) is the result.